# Is it possible track user idle time (mouse/keyboard input) in Linux (without external libraries or programs)

Tags: python, linux

So far my research has failed me to find a way how to track user activity natively in Python under Linux (gui based) - closest thing i could find is to use the `"w | awk '{if (NR!=1) {print $1,$5 }}'"` and `'who -u -H'` commands and read the context with Popen stdout, however it doesn't seem to work under CentOS 7 - at least not when i try and run it in a loop - it seems something is resetting the timer if that command actually works - strange thing is if that's what's happening is the screen saver works and locks the screen - so the OS certainly doesn't use that to track user activity. I am running centos7 under VM on windows 10 if that matters.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: `w` / `who` measures CPU time used, that has nothing to do w/ interactive or not. If a process runs as the user (even the screensaver will do ;}) the counter is going up.

Comment: @tink thx for explaining that to me! I thought about it at one point - idk why i dismissed it lol. Thx again!